# Time stamp but the stamp needs to be in another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm trying to make a KPI that is dependent on completion of task. And I need to time stamp in order to pull this off.

I can make regular time stamps. But what I need is that the time stamp needs to record in different sheet in the same spreadsheet.

I have a master sheet where my employees record and register all calls that come through. It's called "MASTER SHEET".
And a KPI SHEET where I need to record the time /time stamp here/

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "MASTER SHEET" ) 
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) 
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this is where I'm stuck. 
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

This function only stamps in the same sheet so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, that won't do. Since there are thousand of calls registered every day, I won't be able to copy everything to the other sheet. Or did I not get your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== 'MASTER SHEET' || e.range.columnStart !== 2) return;
e.source.getSheetByName('KPI SHEET')
    .getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4)
    .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : '');
}
```

Comment: can I display both date and time?

Comment: To see date and time in one cell format the cell(column) as date/time via the 123-button in the spreadsheet-menu.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured it out.